# Detect when computer goes to sleep (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible at all to detect if the computer that a website is running on goes *into* sleep mode? I've figured out how to use beacon requests to detect if the tab is closed and I've seen answers on how to detect if we just got *out* of sleep, but I can't seem to find if there's a way to detect going into sleep mode.

I thought that maybe not since when the computer is in sleep, you can't execute anything, but maybe there's something like the beacon request where it executes right before actually going into sleep mode?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the server computer goes to sleep?

Comment: Or do you mean the computer running the browser that's accessing the website?

Comment: I think just about anything regarding sleep mode is OS-specific, I don't think there's generic JavaScript code for it.

Comment: like @Barmar says as any system specific thing like configuration, performance, resource consumption are private user data and broswere don't expose them by any native API. But maybe exist some flag allowing this or extension to browser which can add this API. But any this kind decision has to be conscious user decision